# How to properly create an object from two existing objects

Tags: javascript, reactjs, object, state

i have collected two diferents objects form an api and i want to combine them into a single one before passing it to a child component.

I tried to loop one of them to create the third one into ComponentDidUpdate (maybe not the correct approach), and this pops up an error: "Maximum update depth exceeded. This can happen when a component repeatedly calls setState inside componentWillUpdate or componentDidUpdate. React limits the number of nested updates to prevent infinite loops."

```js
export default class Router extends Component {

    state = {
        posts : [],
        secciones : [],
        postSeccion : [],
    }

    componentWillMount() {
        this.obtenerPublicaciones(); //calling api
        this.obtenerSecciones(); //calling api
    }

    componentDidUpdate(prevProps, prevState) {

      this.createPostSeccionArray();


    }

    createPostSeccionArray() {
      const posts = [...this.state.posts];
      const secciones = [...this.state.secciones];

      //check if the two objects were fetched (sometimes didn't finish fetching one of them)
      if(posts.length !== 0 && secciones.length !== 0 ) {

        let postSeccionArray = [];

        posts.forEach(element => {

          const postSeccionElement = {};
          const actualPost = element;
          const actualSeccion = secciones.find(el => el.id == actualPost.id);
          postSeccionElement.post = actualPost;
          postSeccionElement.seccion = actualSeccion;
          postSeccionArray = [...postSeccionArray, postSeccionElement];
        });

        this.setState({
          postSeccion: postSeccionArray,
        })
      }

    }
}
```

This is the output array of objects im expecting:

```
[{
  "post": {
    "id": 1,
    "titulo": "Publicación 1",
    "cuerpo": "<p>test <b>asdasd</b></p>",
    "seccion": 1,
    "fecha_creacion": "2019-04-16T15:16:36.181618Z",
    "fecha_edicion": "2019-04-16T15:16:36.181651Z",
    "autor": 1
  },
  "seccion": {
    "id": 1,
    "nombre": "Deportes",
    "descripcion": "test"
  }
}]
```

Comment: What is you current output ?

Comment: You need to add condition before your setState, else it will end up in infinite loop

Comment: I am confused, why is the initial state of `posts` and `secciones` initialised as arrays with you say they are objects? (I know arrays are objects in js, but you understand my query

Comment: Can you specify what `posts` and `secciones` independently look like?

Comment: @JibinJoseph they look just like they are in the third object

Comment: So are they single objects in an array? `[ { post: { ... }} ]`

Comment: @JibinJoseph Yes, an array of posts and an array of sections. I want to merge them, to reuse in other child components

Comment: I see you are matching the id of the post with that of the section and then concatenating. So I believe the section array is not a single object but an array of many objects, with a specific ID `[ { section: { id:1 } , { id: 2 }, ..} ]` . Is that correct?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on what you have right now, the following will fix it.

```
  componentDidUpdate(prevProps, prevState) {
    if(!prevState.postSeccion.length > 0){
      this.createPostSeccionArray();
    }
  }
```

However, I will wait for more clarity from your side, after which I will edit this answer.

Comment: Consider up voting / accepting the solution that worked for you :)

Answer (score 0):

To merge 2 object (or more) you can use the spread operator

```js
const a = {
  prop1 : "value1",
  prop2 : 23455,
  prop3 : "Hello"
}

const b = {
  prop2 : 67899,
  prop4 : "Workl"
}

const c = {...a, ...b}
console.log(c)
```

if you want the content of an object other you can do something like

```
const secciones = { // stuff };

const newObj = {
  prop1 : ...
  prop2 : ...
  secciones : {...secciones}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Firstly you can use the map function to refactoring your createPostSeccionArray method :

```
export default class Router extends Component {
  state = {
    posts: [],
    secciones: [],
    postSeccion: []
  }

  componentWillMount() {
    Promise.all(this.obtenerPublicaciones(), this.obtenerSecciones()).then(_ =>
      this.createPostSeccionArray()
    )
  }

  createPostSeccionArray() {
    const posts = [...this.state.posts]
    const secciones = [...this.state.secciones]

    // check if the two objects were fetched (sometimes didn't finish fetching one of them)
    if (posts.length !== 0 && secciones.length !== 0) {
      const postSeccionArray = posts.map(element => {
        const actualSeccion = secciones.find(el => el.id == element.id)
        return {
          post: element,
          seccion: actualSeccion
        }
      })

      this.setState({
        postSeccion: postSeccionArray
      })
    }
  }
}
```

I guess you want to create your post section array only when you are mounting the component. so can you use promise like I suggested to call createPostSeccionArray once ?

Comment: This will still end in inifinite loop as you're calling setState without any condition, you need to end some sort of condition when to update state instead of updating without any check

Comment: We don't call componentDidUpdate anymore, so there is no infinite loop

Comment: Read this [UNSAFE_componentWillMount](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#unsafe_componentwillmount)